# FastAPI finish streaming function in StreamingResponse even if client closed the connection

Tags: http, stream, fastapi

I think the title is pretty self explanatory.

FastAPI automatically closes the connection and cancels an operation if the client disconnects.

Is there an easy way (not a celery-redis type solution) to have the server finish running the generator function regardless?

Comment: These kinds of operations shouldn't be coupled with client connects. If you want to avoid celery redis, why don't you go with Background Tasks provided by FastAPI?

Comment: Because I wanted to have the response stream to the user IF they didn't close the connection, but to finish running the generator function regardless.

I ended up using a redis hash coupled with a zset (operation_id: datetime) with a worker. Just adds a bunch of complexity but I'm guessing there's no way around it 